# Problems with the sticky div

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, sticky

fixed div through position:sticky and after scrolling navbar which is fixed overlaps div. How can this be fixed?
Navbar from bootstrap

I am new to frontend, so I used only padding, but it does not look nice, everything is not flat in relation to other blocks
I am new to frontend, so I used only padding, but it does not look nice, everything is not flat in relation to other blocks

Comment: could you provide a few screenshots please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [**not** a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212)_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `z-index` property in CSS, imagine you have 2 `div`s, ***div-1*** which has it's position sticky and and ***div-2***

the code would be:

```
.div-1 {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 0;
}

.div-2 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you want please write your code here, before that try the code below and see its work or not

```css
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#your-id-name-for-navbar{
z-index:99; 
}
```